# Converting ArrayList<String[]> to String[][] or Object[][]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, classcastexception

**I wanted to dynamically generate an array of fixed sized String[] (String[][] object)**, filled w. Strings of rows values from db to create JTable.

To do that, I used ArrayList of String[], dynamically filled it up. And then convert it to Array using list.toArray().
But .toArray() only convert the list into single dimension Array either Object[] or T[].

I need String[][] / Object[][] to use the JTable constructor.

The code

```
Object[][] dlist = (Object[][]) al.toArray();
```

generates: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;

```
ers = pdao.getEmployeeResultSet(prs.getInt("PROJ_ID"));
ArrayList<String[]> alist = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while (ers.next()){
    String eid = ers.getString("EMP_ID");
    String ename = ers.getString("EMP_NAME");
    String gend = ers.getString("GENDER");
    String bd = ers.getString("BIRTHDATE");
    String addr = ers.getString("ADDRESS");
    String city = ers.getString("City");

    String[] str = {eid, ename, gend, bd, addr, city};
    alist.add(str);
}
Object[][] dlist = (Object[][]) al.toArray();
String[] cnames = {"EMP_ID","EMP_NAME","GENDER","BIRTHDATE","Address","City"};

jtable = new JTable(dlist, cnames);
```

I used the tuturial on : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java to create JTable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would just create the double array myself, if you really wanted to:

```
public static String[][] getDArray(final ArrayList<String[]> aList) {
    final int size = aList.size();
    final String[][] ans = new String[size][];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ans[i] = aList.get(i);

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: This method is not typesafe. `String[][] s = getDArray(list);` will result in a ClassCastException.

Comment: Making the method generic appears to be more-or-less not be possible in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110993/creating-generic-two-dimensional-array-using-class-object .  Which is unfortunate, but a pretty simple fix for the above code (just don't make it generic).

Comment: And I really don't understand why this would not be possible.  Every object in Java is a pointer (the exact same size pointer for a particular JVM).  So creating a generic array of pointers should not be difficult.  I understand if this were C and they were structs--you wouldn't know how big to make each slot for the array, but that's not how Java implements an array.  Think about declaring a `new String[10]`--a `String` is a variable sized data structure, so it cannot possibly create room for 10 arbitrary `String` objects--instead it just makes 10 slots for `String` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
String[][] dlist = alist.toArray(new String[][]{});
```

The array you pass to the method can alternatively be used as the actual array that will be returned if you know the size (which you do with `alist.size()`), but it's really useful for the **type of array that you want.**

You can actually confirm this with

```
String[][] holder = new String[alist.size()][];
String[][] returned = alist.toArray(holder);
System.out.println(holder == returned);
```

will print

```
true
```

Now, obviously, since arrays are covariant, you can also do

```
Object[][] dlist = al.toArray(holder);
```